# Replace the last occurrence of <p> tag in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking to replace the last occurrence of P tag in a string.

```
$bodytext = preg_replace(strrev("/<p>/"),strrev('<p class="last">'),strrev($bodytext),1);
$bodytext = strrev($bodytext);
```

This works, but can it be done without using strrev? Is there a regex solution?

Something like :

```
$bodytext = preg_replace('/<p>.?$/', '<p class="last">', $bodytext);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My shortened version:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($bodytext);
$paragraphs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
$last_p = $paragraphs->item($paragraphs->length - 1);
$last_p->setAttribute("class", "last");
$bodytext = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use the DOM instead, Look into [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Comment: If you're doing that so that you can style the last `p`, you should consider using `p:last` instead.

Comment: That was the first thing I looked at, but I would still like to support IE 7 & 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people will complain that DOMDocument is more verbose for parsing HTML then a regex. But verbosity is okay if it means using the *right* tool for the job.

```
$previous_value = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$string = '<p>hi, mom</p><p>bye, mom</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$paragraphs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
$last_p = $paragraphs->item($paragraphs->length - 1);
$last_p->setAttribute("class", "last");
$new_string = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveHTML()));
libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($previous_value);

echo htmlentities($new_string);
// <p>hi, mom</p><p class="last">bye, mom</p>
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/D2ADzt)

Comment: I appreciate the code example. I will have a look and test the parse speed results - but it does seem excessive considering the string is always around 500 characters and only contains one <a href=""> link and 2 sets of <p></p> tags.

Comment: It's going to be fast. Don't associate speed with lines of code. And don;t let speed be the only factor. Regex's aren't made for processing HTML. DOMDocument is.

Comment: I modified my post - is there any issues if I used my shortened version of your code?

Comment: There won't be any issues unless the string you pass contains invalid HTML at any point. Then you will get warnings generated by PHP.

Comment: Ok thanks, CKEditor is handling the html output so that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)?

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$string = '<p>hi, mom</p><p>bye, mom</p>';
$doc = str_get_html($string);
$doc->find('p', -1)->class = 'last';
echo $doc;
// <p>hi, mom</p><p class="last">bye, mom</p>
```